# Jquery load into multiple divs

Tags: jquery

I want to load multiple divs from 1 file. Im trying these way:

```
$.get('msg.php', function(data) {
    $("#title").html($(data).find('#title'));
    $("#title2").html($(data).find('#title2'));
});
```

And msg.php file

```
<div id="title">elo2</div>
<div id="title2">elo2</div>
```

And these not working, not loading

Comment: Are you sure your data var contains what you want? Also, you could try to use a JSON return in your msg.php

Comment: What your expected result and what is the actual result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $ operator acts on the DOM Document (the HTML on the webpage).

If you want to process another document (in this case one described by the msg.php file) you need to parse it (cf [jQuery.parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)).

Note that your payload is not valid XML, you would need to add a root element.

So my recommendation: If I understand you correctly and you just need to pass these data to the client it would  be easier to produce json with msg.php:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "title" => "elo2",
    "title2" => "elo2"
); 
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Resulting in this json string:

```
{
    "title" : "elo2"
    "title2" : "elo2"
}
```

Then you can access the properties directly from the data object, no need for any parsing:

```
$.get('msg.php', function(data) {
    $("#title").html(data.title);
    $("#title2").html(data.title2);
}
```

(there is also an example of this on the [jQUery.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) page, the very last one)

Comment: ok now my msg.php looks like:
`<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        "title" => "elo2",
        "title2" => "elo2"
    )
);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>`

and im getting `[{"title":"elo2","title2":"elo2"}]` and how to update these on site

Comment: $.get('msg.php', function(data) {
    $("#title").html(data.title);
    $("#title2").html(data.title2);
});

Comment: I cannot post more than two links in my answer so here is a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6w6rLy2b/1/

You might also return ´$arr = array( "title" => "elo2", "title2" => "elo2" )´ that would make accessing the first array element of the response via [0] unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Since your elements are all at the root level, they are all matched in `$(data)`. You have to use `.filter('#title')` to reduce the already matched set.`.find('#title')` will fail because it searches for children.

```
$.get('msg.php', function(data) {
    $("#title").text($(data).filter('#title').text());
    $("#title2").text($(data).filter('#title2').text());
})
```

Alternatively, you can use `.load()` to load the entire contents of the AJAX response into a targeted `div`. Since your response `div`s match the destination, this might make sense for your code. Just wrap the `#title` and `#title2` in a `div` with ID `messages`.

```
<div id="messages">
  <div id="title"></div>
  <div id="title2"></div>
</div>
```

Then use `.load()` instead.

```
$('#messages').load('msg.php');
```

http://codepen.io/kylebedell/pen/XdjaMd

Comment: I don't want to load whole file into 2 divs i want to load div1 into div1 and div2 into div2

Answer (score 0):

If the `<div>` elements has parent element, you can use `$(parrentelement + ' > div).html(data);`

Here it is an example:
 https://jsfiddle.net/bbogdanov/n6LsyLpz/